# Diff & patch files through R (win/linux/mac)

Tags: diff, r

Is there a way I can "diff" two files from within R and store/apply the patch later?  I want something that will work on Windows, Linux and macOS.

I've looked at the package "diffobj" which doesn't seem to be able to patch and I've looked into "git2r" which doesn't seem to have git's patch functionality.  Is there something else I'm not aware of?  Ideally, I want something that will work on Windows, Linux and macOS.